# MySQL Como asignar el valor de una Foreing Key, usando el valor de la primary key de otra tabla

Tags: mysql

empecé a aprender programación hace poquito y estoy haciendo una pequeña aplicación de escritorio. Básicamente tiene dos partes, una agenda de clientes (tabla clientes) y una cuenta corriente para estos clientes (tabla cta_corrientes) estoy usando MYSQL para el manejo de las bases de datos:
DROP DATABASE prueba;

```
CREATE DATABASE prueba;
USE prueba;

CREATE TABLE clientes (
    id_cliente INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    nombre VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    telefono INT NOT NULL, 
    direccion varchar (50),
    observaciones varchar (150),
    PRIMARY KEY (id_cliente)
);

CREATE TABLE cta_corriente (
    id_cta  INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    id_cliente INT NOT NULL,
    debe INT,
    haber INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id_cta),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_cliente) REFERENCES clientes(id_cliente)
);
```

Tengo esas dos tablas, la pregunta es: cómo puedo hacer que la FK de la tabla cta_corriente se asigne automaticamente cuando inserto un cliente en la tabla cliente (osea que al insertar un cliente la pk de esa tabla, asigne automaticamente la FK de la tabla cta_corriente) ??

desde ya si no hice el post de manera correcta (trate de encontrar en google la solucion o algo similar y no lo logre), agradezco la paciencia a mi consulta. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Justo despues de insertar datos en la tabla clientes, puedes asignar a una variable el valor Last_Insert_Id y despues se lo insertas a la tabla cta_corriente. Referencia [MySql LAST_INSERT_ID](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

Comment: Excelente, me funciono como me lo dijiste. Muchas Gracias!

Comment: Me da gusto haberte ayudado, un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Generalmente la id se pasa por parámetro URL, esto quiere decir, que al momento de hacer un post, el controlador php o webservice que recibe el post recibe la id desde la ruta desde la que viene.

Por ejempl. Si la ruta de tu página es:

```
tupagina.xl/usuario/{id?}/post
```

En el controlador obtienes la id desde la URL que proviene el HTTP request.

Otra manera, es pasando el post por un input hidden, o por data de algún componente hecho con javascript.

De todas estas maneras, el $request puede obtener los valores de la id correcta. Para verificar que no te están haciendo XSS también puedes enviar un token de validación.

Comment: Hola como estas, la app es de escritorio y  la estoy haciendo en Python Muchas gracias!